# flask.ext.script is deprecated

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following error:

```
web_1  | /code/app/__init__.py:4: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.script is deprecated, use flask_script instead.
web_1  |   from flask.ext.script import Manager
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
web_1  |     from app import app
web_1  |   File "/code/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
web_1  |     from flask.ext.script import Manager
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 110, in load_module
web_1  |     raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
web_1  | ImportError: No module named flask.ext.script
```

and then I made the change but then it says:

```
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
web_1  |     from app import app
web_1  |   File "/code/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
web_1  |     from flask_script import Manager
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_script'
```

I'm a bit confused on how Flask was upgraded. Any advice? Should I fix my flask to an older version, maybe the dependencies aren't upgraded yet?

Using sqlalchemy and migrate:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
```

Answer (score 15):

I had to explicitly install `Flask-Script`

Then the imports would work with

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
```

Answer (score -3):

All available extensions' name are listed at:

> http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/

Using `pip install [Extension Name]` to install the extensions you needed.